# about allocating 2 dimentional array

Tags: arrays, memory

I'm sorry about my poor English in advance.
I'm using VS2013.
I was making dynamic array, this is my code.

```
char ** files = new char*[4];
cout << files << endl;
files[0] = new char[4 * 50];
cout << files[0][0] << endl;

for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    files[i] = files[i - 1] + 50;
}
```

I think if I change 4 and 4*50 to variable. I can make dynamic array. uh.. I mean dynamic allocation. but here's the problem.

```
//do something...
delete files[0];
delete files;
```

this code occurs error. probably I delete something twice.
(Block Type is Valid pHead->nBlockUse )
However, in my opinion, first, I must delete char array by deleting files[0]
and then I have to delete char pointer array by deleting files.
but mighty compiler says I'm doing wrong.
Help me!~

Comment: Can you show us the error message?

Comment: (Block Type is Valid pHead->nBlockUse ) this is the error message

Comment: expression: _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(puserData)

Comment: I think It's about string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you do not use the right C++ primitive to delete an array.

If you allocate, a single object with new, you can use delete to deallocate it:

```
char *p = new char;
...
delete p;
```

When you allocate an array of objects with new T[], you have to use delete[] to deallocate the array:

```
char *p = new char[N];
...
delete[] p;
```

So in your example, you should do:

```
delete[] (files[0]);
delete[] files;
```